# ¿Cómo cambiar el valor de cierto número de variables dependiendo de la respuesta del usuario?

Tags: python, pycharm

Estoy creando un conversor de peso en modo consola bastante sencillo. Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario proporcione el primer tipo de magnitud, el valor de las variables cambie en base a esa respuesta. Por ejemplo, si yo escribo "libra", entonces las demás variables de equivalencia cambien su valor para proceder a la conversión. Intenté con la instrucción `if`, lo cual funciona muy bien a la hora de cambiar el valor de las variables. El problema nace cuando pide la segunda magnitud y debe proceder a la conversión, ya que la única forma que se me ocurrió de que el programa supiera a qué magnitud deseaba convertir era usando `input`, y luego de eso crear más condicionales `if` para que pudiera elegir el valor de conversión.

Lo he probado y funciona muy bien, el problema es que pienso añadir más magnitudes, lo cual implicaría una instrucción `if` por cada cada tipo de conversión posible. Lo cual a mi parecer, hace que el código sea innecesariamente más largo de lo que debería. Mi pregunta es ¿Hay alguna forma de automatizarlo y simplificarlo para que el programa cambie los valores de las variables y sepa cuál equivalencia de conversión el usuario va a usar?

Mi código es este:

```py
    print("Conversor de peso")
    print("----------------------------------------------")

    while True:
        Magnitud1 = str
        Magnitud2 = str
        Cantidad = str
        print("¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: ")
        ask = input()
        if ask == "salir" or ask == "Salir":
            break

        if ask == "convertir" or ask == "Convertir":
            kilogramo = float
            gramo = float
            Convalue = float
            resultado = float

            Q1 = input("¿Qué magnitud desea convertir? ")
            if Q1 == "libra":
                kilogramo = 0.45
                gramo = 453.59

            Q2 = input("¿A qué magnitud desea convertirlo? ")

            Q3 = input("¿Cuántas unidades? ")
            Cantidad = float(Q3)

            if Q2 == "kilogramo":
                Convalue = kilogramo
                resultado = Cantidad * Convalue

            if Q2 == "gramo":
                Convalue = gramo
                resultado = Cantidad * Convalue

            print("El resultado es: " and resultado)
            print()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para no tener que repetir mucho código, una opción muy simple es usar un diccionario para definir las equivalencias. Si además tomas una unidad como base, por ejemplo el gramo, puedes convertir cualquier unidad de entrada a gramos y luego los gramos a la unidad de salida, reduciendo así el diccionario.

Unas cuantas observaciones:

- En Python no tienes que declarar el tipo de las variables. De hecho una variable como tal, estrictamente hablando, no tiene tipo según el concepto de C por ejemplo, es solo **un identificador o nombre siempre asociado a la referencia de un objeto cualquiera en memoria**, el cual puede ser un objeto `int`, `float`, `None`, `list`, o cualquier otro objeto. Tampoco es necesario que las inicialices en tu caso, pero si las quieres inicializar no hagas `Magnitud1 = str`, esto asocia `Magnitud1` al builtin `str`, una función, no a una cadena vacía. Para inicializar a una cadena vacía haz simplemente `Magnitud1 = ""`, lo mismo con los `floats`, `resultado = 0.0`. Si sería correcto hacer `Magnitud1 = str()` y `resultado = float()` (observa los paréntesis de llamada) pero es más ineficiente que usar un literal.

  [A partir de Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) se habilitó la posibilidad de hacer anotaciones de tipo en variables, no obstante esto no declara de forma estática una variable, Python sigue siendo de tipado dinámico ("duck typing"), es solo informativo o para que sea usado por herramientas como [MyPY](http://mypy-lang.org/) que permite una comprobación estática de tipos para evitar que se asignen objetos de un tipo distinto al especificado por el programador a una variable dada, facilitando la depuración y previniendo errores relacionados con ello. Si quisieras hacer uso de esto, la sintaxis sería:

  ```
  q1: str             # Sin valor inicial
  q1: str = ""        # Con valor inicial
  gramo: float        # Sin valor inicial   
  gramo: float = 0.0  # Con valor inicial
  ```
- Puedes usar `str.lower` para pasar la cadena de entrada a minúscula, facilitando la comparación en el condicional.
- En vez de hacer:

  ```
  print("¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: ")
  ask = input()
  ```

  pasa la cadena a `input` y te ahorras la llamada a una función:

  ```
  ask = input("¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: ")
  ```
- El `and` en el último `print` no tiene sentido, `print` acepta un número indeterminado de objetos a imprimir:

  ```
  print("El resultado es:", resultado)
  ```

  O puedes formatear la cadena:

  ```
  print("El resultado es: {}.".format(resultado))
  print(f"El resultado es: {resultado}.") # f-strings, Python >= 3.6
  ```
- Por convención, no debes usar mayúsculas para nombrar variables, métodos o funciones, las mayúsculas se reservan para "constantes" (todo en mayúsculas, por ejemplo `PI = 3.14`) y para los nombres de clases (dónde se usa CamelCase, por ejemplo `class SoyUnaClase:`). Para más información puedes verte [Guia de estilo para código Python- PEP 8 en Español](http://recursospython.com/pep8es.pdf)

Tu código podría quedar:

```
print("Conversor de peso")
print("----------------------------------------------")

CONV = {'gramo': 1,
        'kilogramo': 1000,
        'libra': 453.5923
        }

while True:
    ask = input("¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: ").lower()
    if ask == "salir":
        break

    elif ask == "convertir":
        magnitud_entrada = input("¿Qué magnitud desea convertir? ").lower()
        eq1 = CONV.get(magnitud_entrada)
        if eq1 is None:
            print("Magnitud de entrada no disponible")
            continue

        magnitud_salida = input("¿A qué magnitud desea convertirlo? ").lower()
        eq2 = CONV.get(magnitud_salida)
        if eq2 is None:
            print("Magnitud de salida no disponible")
            continue

        unidades = float(input("¿Cuántas unidades? "))
        resultado = (unidades * eq1) / eq2

        print(f"El resultado es: {resultado} {magnitud_salida}s.\n")

    else:
        print("Opción no válida")
```

> ¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: convertir
>   ¿Qué magnitud desea convertir? libra
>   ¿A qué magnitud desea convertirlo? gramo
>   ¿Cuántas unidades? 23
>   El resultado es: 10432.6229 gramos.
>
> ¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: convertir
>   ¿Qué magnitud desea convertir? libra
>   ¿A qué magnitud desea convertirlo? kilogramo
>   ¿Cuántas unidades? 23
>   El resultado es: 10.4326229 kilogramos.
>
> ¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: convertir
>   ¿Qué magnitud desea convertir? gramo
>   ¿A qué magnitud desea convertirlo? kilogramo
>   ¿Cuántas unidades? 4256
>   El resultado es: 4.256 kilogramos.
>
> ¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: convertir
>   ¿Qué magnitud desea convertir? kilogramo
>   ¿A qué magnitud desea convertirlo? gramo
>   ¿Cuántas unidades? 7.23
>   El resultado es: 7230.0 gramos.
>
> ¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: convertir
>   ¿Qué magnitud desea convertir? kilogramos
>   ¿A qué magnitud desea convertirlo? libra
>   ¿Cuántas unidades? 7
>   El resultado es: 15.43236073451864 libras.
>
> ¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: salir

No siempre la conversión es tan simple, como ocurre con las escalas de temperatura por ejemplo. No obstante la idea puede ser la misma, nuestro diccionario puede contener funciones como valores:

```
print("Conversor de peso")
print("----------------------------------------------")

CONV = {'celsius': {'fahrenheit': lambda c: c * 1.8 + 32,
                    'kelvin': lambda c: c + 273.15
                    },
        'fahrenheit': {'celsius': lambda f: (f - 32) / 1.8,
                       'kelvin': lambda f: (f + 459.67) * 5 / 9
                       },
        'kelvin': {'celsius': lambda k: k - 273.15,
                   'fahrenheit': lambda k: 1.8 * (k - 273) + 32
                   },
        }

while True:
    ask = input("¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: ").lower()
    if ask == "salir":
        break

    elif ask == "convertir":
        magnitud_entrada = input("¿Qué magnitud desea convertir? ").lower()
        con_funs = CONV.get(magnitud_entrada)
        if con_funs is None:
            print("Magnitud de entrada no disponible")
            continue

        magnitud_salida = input("¿A qué magnitud desea convertirlo? ").lower()
        if magnitud_entrada == magnitud_salida:
            resultado = float(input("¿Cuántas unidades? "))
        else:
            con_fun = con_funs.get(magnitud_salida)
            if con_fun is None:
                print("Magnitud de salida no disponible")
                continue
            unidades = float(input("¿Cuántas unidades? "))
            resultado = con_fun(unidades)

        print(f"El resultado es: {resultado} {magnitud_salida}.\n")

    else:
        print("Opción no válida")
```

> ¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: convertir
>   ¿Qué magnitud desea convertir? kelvin
>   ¿A qué magnitud desea convertirlo? fahrenheit
>   ¿Cuántas unidades? 293
>   El resultado es: 68.0 fahrenheit.
>
> ¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: convertir
>   ¿Qué magnitud desea convertir? kelvin
>   ¿A qué magnitud desea convertirlo? celsius
>   ¿Cuántas unidades? 293
>   El resultado es: 19.850000000000023 celsius.
>
> ¿Qué desea hacer? Convertir | Salir: convertir
>   ¿Qué magnitud desea convertir? fahrenheit
>   ¿A qué magnitud desea convertirlo? kelvin
>   ¿Cuántas unidades? 140
>   El resultado es: 333.15000000000003 kelvin.

---

### Edición

Voy a intentar responder a las dudas planteadas en comentarios de la forma más concisa posible:

- **`lambda`**: es una palabra clave que permite declarar funciones lambda o también llamadas funciones anónimas. Son funciones que no son asociadas a un nombre o identificador (aunque el intérprete si que les asigna un nombre común a todas ellas (`<lambda>`), pero esto es otra historia). Además del nombre, tiene otras diferencias con una función definida con `def`, entre ellas:

  - Se escriben en una sola línea ejecutable.
  - Su contenido tiene que ser una única expresión, cuya evaluación determina el valor de retorno.
  - No pueden contener estamentos (`return`, `continue`, `raise`, `yield`, etc).

  En el caso que nos atañe:

  ```
  ONV = {'celsius': {'fahrenheit': lambda c: c * 1.8 + 32}}
  ```

  sería lago similar a hacer:

  ```
  def celsius_to_fahrenheit(c):
      retunr c * 1.8 + 32

  ONV = {'celsius': {'fahrenheit': celsius_to_fahrenheit}}
  ```

  Explicar a fondo que son las funciones lambda, cuándo usarlas, diferencias, ventajas y desventajas con respecto a funciones normales, etc requeriría varias preguntas, por lo que no voy a ahondar en ello. Si alguien está interesado en profundisar en el tema y el inglés no es un problema, el siguiente artículo de Andre Burgaud en realpython.com es una buena referencia:

  - https://realpython.com/python-lambda/#anonymous-functions
- **f-string o literales de cadena formateados**: es una nueva forma disponible a partir de Python 3.6 para formatear cadenas (literales de cadena) que se añade al viejo formateo por `%` y `str.format`/`format()`. Se definen anteponiendo una `f` al literal de cadena y permite especificar dianas de reemplazo mediante `{}` al igual que hace `str.format`. La **expresión encerrada dentro de los corchetes será evaluada y su resultado es usado para substituir la diana en la cadena**:

  ```
  a = 2
  b = 3
  print(f"{a} elevado a {b} es {a ** b}")
  ```

  > 2 elevado a 3 es 8

  La sintaxis es muy simple y legible y además son mucho más eficientes que el formateo mediante `%` o `format`/`str.format` para más información podemos mirar [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Comment: Creo que entiendo el concepto. En `CONV` he de agregar el "diccionario" que mencionas, en base a una unidad en específico. Por ello es que gramo es igual a 1 y el resto son equivalencias en gramos. La función `CONV.get()` consulta esa lista para comprobar si hay alguna coincidencia con la entrada del usuario, y si es así, usa ese valor. A la hora de la conversión, lo que hace es multiplicar la cantidad dada por el usuario por el valor de la primera magnitud y luego lo divide dentro del valor asignado a la segunda variable. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Hola Kevin, exacto, esa es la idea del primer ejemplo (aunque hay muchas formas de implementarlo claro está, esta es muy simple si la conversión es solo multiplicar o dividir por una constante).  Solo precisar que `dict.get` busca la clave en el diccionario, si existe retorna su valor, ni no existe retorna `None` por defecto (por eso lo de `if eq1 is None`), aunque podemos especificar otro valor: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: En cuanto a las observaciones, me han servido mucho. `str.lower` hace que a la hora de trabajar con esa cadena, sea convertida en minúsculas para evitar errores. Lo de `and` lo coloqué porque no recordaba cómo concatenar distintos valores y variables; mi error. En cuanto a lo de las variables, sí era consciente de que no hay necesidad de declarar su tipo, pero necesitaba mantenerla creada antes de proceder a la conversión y no sabía que hacer, pero con lo de agregarle los paréntesis, quedándome `q1 = str()`, por ejemplo. Lo de las minúsculas lo desconocía completamente. Lo tomaré en cuenta.

Comment: Ahora bien, hay un par de cosas que no me quedaron claras, principalmente en el ejemplo que me diste sobre temperaturas. Entiendo bien la parte de las fórmulas para convertir, pero no entiendo qué es lo que hace `lambda`. Desconocía completamente esa instrucción. Otra cosa que no entendí fue en el penúltimo print, ya que inicia con una f, y luego vienen las cadenas que imprime.

Comment: Una última pregunta. Si quisiera, por ejemplo, crear un conversor unificado que al principio me pregunte si quiero convertir peso, volumen, temperatura, etc. y en base a eso cree los distintos diccionarios a emplear ¿Qué función necesitaría? ¿O sería más práctico crear un conversor por cada tipo (Masa, tiempo, volumen, etc.) y en un mismo proyecto unificado ejecutar cada archivo `.py` según se requiera? Soy nuevo en Python, y agradezco cualquier observación y/o consejo.

Comment: Kevin en cuanto a lambda y f-strings he añadido al final de la respuesta unas pequeñas aclaraciones. Son temas que dan para mucho más, pero sería extender mucho la respuesta (que ya es larga de por si XD...) y además son dudas que están fuera de la pregunta original. No obstante, si tienes alguna duda concreta sobre ellas no dudes en crear una nueva pregunta exponiéndola.

Comment: En cuanto a la última duda, tienes muchas formas de implementarlo. Por ejemplo, puedes definir un diccionario para la conversión de peso, otro para volúmne, etc y usar un condicional para seleccionar el diccionario a utilizar. Puede crear un solo diccionario anidado `{"peso": {"gramo": 1, ...},  "volumen": {"litro": 1,....},...}` y seleccionar igual que se hace arriba usando get.

Comment: Si usas algo similar al segundo ejemplo (el de las temperaturas), no necesitas especificar realmente  si las unidades son masa, volumen, etc. Dado que cada magnitud tiene como valor un diccionario con las magnitudes a las que puede convertirse, en el momento que se elige metro y litro por ejemplo el segundo condicional saltaría dado que litros no seria una clave del diccionario asociado a metros (como el diccionario asociado a celsius no tiene ninguna clave metro por ejemplo, pero si kelvin y fahrenheit).

Comment: Dividirlo o no en distintos módulos es uan eleccion que debes tomar tu en función de preferencias y de la estructura de tu app.  Lo que si haría como mínimo sería definir el diccionario o diccionario y cualquier función de conversión en  otro módulo (o modulos) y la lógica en otro para (importando el módulo con los diccionarios y funciones de conversión).